# Custom torchtext dataset

Tags: python, dataset, torchtext

I would like to use the BucketIterator function provided by torch text in an custom dataset.

What I have is a couple of lists, source and target, which contain text.

I don't find any clear guide for building your own torchtext.data.Dataset.